# Error in Li Mak test after fitting DCC GARCH model

Tags: r

From other posts on this platform, I found that Li Mak test on the standardised residuals is more appropriate to test a fitted GARCH model than the Ljung Box test. The Weighted.LM.test() from the WeightedPortTest package in R is used for it.

I’m trying this code but I’m getting an error. Since it a univariate test, I have extracted standardised residuals and cvar from the slot name fit:

```
std.resid1<-dccfit@mfit$stdresid[,1]
cvar1<-dccfit@mfit$cvar[,1]
Weighted.LM.test(std.resid1, cvar1, lag=10)

Error in std.resid1, cvar1, : Length of x and h.t must match
```

How do it get this to work? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does anyone know how to run a Li-Mak test in R?

Comment: You can use the same function as in the question with the weighted flag equal to FALSE, check https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WeightedPortTest/versions/1.0/topics/Weighted.LM.test

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not take standardized residuals so
instead of dccfit@mfit$stdresid[,1], take: dccfit@model$residuals[,1].

Then, in the documentation of the Weighted.LM.test, it says that h.t should be a numeric vector of the conditional variances, thus take instead:

dccfit@model$sigma[,1]^2

run the test:
Weighted.LM.test(dccfit@model$residuals[,1], dccfit@model$sigma[,1]^2, lag = 2,type = c("correlation", "partial"),fitdf = 1, weighted = FALSE)

Please correct me if I am wrong.